# Можно ли запустить Azure SQL Server на другом порту?

Tags: sql-server, azure, port

Как запустить Azure SQL Server на другом порту?

Comment: Нельзя. Инфраструктура полностью контролируется MS-ом.

Comment: Это без сомнения. Но могут быть такие настройки.Я их не нашел или их нет?

Comment: Их нет (по крайней мере в текущей версии SQL Azure) :(